# using condition in jquery onclick button

Tags: html, jquery, if-statement

Im trying to confirm if the password strength is strong or weak and is the password is strong and when I submit it should have alert message like "You Have Strong Password" and when its weak "Invalid Password"

This is what I am now.

```
function checkPasswordStrength() {
        var passwordStrength = false;
        var number = /([0-9])/;
        var alphabets = /([a-zA-Z])/;
        var special_characters = /([~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,-,_,+,=,?,>,<])/;
        if ($('#password').val().length < 8) {
            $('#password-strength-status').removeClass();
            $('#password-strength-status').addClass('weak-password');
            $('#password-strength-status').html("Weak (should be atleast 8 characters.)");
        } else {
            if ($('#password').val().match(number) && $('#password').val().match(alphabets) && $('#password').val().match(special_characters)) {
                $('#password-strength-status').removeClass();
                $('#password-strength-status').addClass('strong-password');
                $('#password-strength-status').html("Strong");
                return passwordStrength = true;
            } else {
                $('#password-strength-status').removeClass();
                $('#password-strength-status').addClass('medium-password');
                $('#password-strength-status').html("Medium (should include alphabets, numbers and special characters.)");
            }
        }
    }

    $('#btn-submit').click(function () {
        if (passwordStrength == false) {
        alert("INVALID PASSWORD");
        } else {
        alert("You have Strong PASSWORD");
        }

</script>
```

its for Educational Purpose only im just starting jquery..
thank you in advance..

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the variable scope is incorrect. `var passwordStrength` should be put outside of the `checkPasswordStrength` function.

```
var passwordStrength
function checkPasswordStrength() {

    ....
```

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @EyeConic, if the answer solves the problem, mark it as accepted.

Comment: This will not help.  `checkPasswordStrength()` is never called, so `passwordStrength` will never change from whatever you definie it as outside that function (null in this answer). @joel-rosenberg's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function instead of just checking your variable. So rather do

```
$('#btn-submit').click(function () {
    if (checkPasswordStrength() === false) {
```

instead of

```
$('#btn-submit').click(function () {
    if (passwordStrength == false) {
```

Then, instead of `return passwordStrength = true;` you should do just `passwordStrength = true` and add a `return passwordStrength` to the very end of your function so it will return either false or true.